# Query to summarize rows from table with version history

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for help with a SQL query.  Below are the details.

**Database:**  Microsoft SQL Server 2016

**Data Table:**

- It's a "version history" table with 3 columns:  version number, effective date, and end date.
- The version number with an end_dt of 12/31/9999 is considered the "active" version number.
- Users can "restore" prior versions and make them active again.

| version_number | eff_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-13 18:03:26.483 | 2021-04-16 18:35:06.367 |
| 1 | 2021-04-16 18:35:06.370 | 2021-04-19 20:45:38.993 |
| 1 | 2021-04-19 20:45:38.997 | 2021-05-06 16:00:59.990 |
| 2 | 2021-05-06 16:00:59.990 | 2021-05-06 16:13:03.997 |
| 3 | 2021-05-06 16:13:04.000 | 2021-05-06 16:17:23.127 |
| 4 | 2021-05-06 16:17:23.130 | 2021-05-06 16:52:45.250 |
| 4 | 2021-05-06 16:52:45.253 | 2021-05-11 15:36:25.283 |
| 4 | 2021-05-11 15:36:25.283 | 2021-05-14 15:52:50.843 |
| 5 | 2021-05-14 15:52:50.847 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.860 |
| 4 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.863 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.867 |
| 1 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.870 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

**Desired Output:**

- A query to display a consolidated version history where consecutive entries in the version history table are displayed as a single row encompassing the entire date range the version was active.

| version_number | eff_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-13 18:03:26.483 | 2021-04-16 18:35:06.367 |
| 1 | 2021-04-16 18:35:06.370 | 2021-05-06 16:00:59.990 |
| 2 | 2021-05-06 16:00:59.990 | 2021-05-06 16:13:03.997 |
| 3 | 2021-05-06 16:13:04.000 | 2021-05-06 16:17:23.127 |
| 4 | 2021-05-06 16:17:23.130 | 2021-05-14 15:52:50.843 |
| 5 | 2021-05-14 15:52:50.847 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.860 |
| 4 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.863 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.867 |
| 1 | 2021-05-20 17:14:55.870 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

**Question:**
How would one write a SQL statement to generate the Desired Output based on the Data Table?

**SQL Script to create sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    [version_number] [int] NULL,
    [eff_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [end_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.870' AS DateTime), CAST(N'9999-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.847' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.860' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.863' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.867' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.843' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.253' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.130' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.250' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:04.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.127' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:03.997' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.997' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.370' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.993' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (0, CAST(N'2021-04-13T18:03:26.483' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.367' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in two steps, using successive common table expressions (cte).  Firstly, you need a consecutive ranking number within your data.  On the basis of this you can then do a recursive cte, looking at the version_number of consecutive rows (necessarily one apart).  This allows us to create a "batch" number: if the version_number is the same, then we take the previous batch number, if it is different, we increment the previous batch number by one.  Finally we need a simple min and max on the dates grouping by the batch number.  The result looks like this:

```
declare @t1 TABLE (
    [version_number] [int] NULL,
    [eff_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [end_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL
);

INSERT @t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) 
VALUES 
(1, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.870' AS DateTime), CAST(N'9999-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)),
(5, CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.847' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.860' AS DateTime)),
(4, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.863' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.867' AS DateTime)),
(4, CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.843' AS DateTime)),
(4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.253' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime)),
(4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.130' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.250' AS DateTime)),
(3, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:04.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.127' AS DateTime)),
(2, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:03.997' AS DateTime)),
(1, CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.997' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime)),
(1, CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.370' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.993' AS DateTime)),
(0, CAST(N'2021-04-13T18:03:26.483' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.367' AS DateTime));


with rowdata as
(
    SELECT version_number, eff_dt, end_dt, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY eff_dt) rn
    FROM @t1
),
cte_recursive as
(
    SELECT 1 as batchno, rn, version_number, eff_dt, end_dt 
    FROM rowdata
    WHERE version_number = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE WHEN rec.version_number = rd.version_number 
                THEN rec.batchno 
                ELSE rec.batchno + 1 
            END, 
        rd.rn, rd.version_number, rd.eff_dt, rd.end_dt 
    FROM cte_recursive rec 
    INNER JOIN rowdata rd on rec.rn = rd.rn - 1
) 
SELECT 
version_number, min(eff_dt) as eff_dt, max(end_dt) as end_dt 
FROM cte_recursive 
GROUP BY version_number, batchno
```

A couple of points to note.  I prefer to use table variables to temporary tables (has a slight advantage that they don't need to be deleted!).  Secondly you can insert multiple values separated by commas, as I have shown (no need for multiple inserts).

To help you understand how the recursive element works, we begin by a simple select which is the base case, in this case selecting where version_number is 0.  We then build up from that by joining to the recursive part where rn (the value returned by ROW_NUMBER()) is one greater than the value we already have.  We simply need to check for a difference in the version_number between our old value and the new row, to decide if the batch number needs incrementing or not.

You may find it helpful to run these queries one at a time, to help you understand what is happening (for example just run the sub-select that includes the row_number()).

BTW it was good of you to add the create statements.

Comment: In general, we don't put meta commentary into posts. Even in comments, such things are considered ephemeral and generally subject to deletion/removal.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished using `window functions`. It's a variation on the *gaps and islands* problem.

The premise is to identify the islands of consecutive values of the version_number. The first CTE uses `lag` to compare the current row value to the previous row value and marks the start of the Next Group when the values are different. The second CTE uses `sum` as a `window function` to produce a running total of the groups. This provides each group of like version_numbers with its own sequential value.

The final select is then able to `group` by the version_number and its sequential group number, using the min and max dates for each.

Note also that using `windows function` and hitting the source table just once will also be significantly more efficient than a recursive solution.

```
with ng as (
    select *, case when Lag(version_number) over(order by end_dt) = version_number then 0 else 1 end as ng
    from #t1 
), grp as (
    select *, Sum(ng) over(order by end_dt) as grp
    from ng
)
select version_number, Min(eff_dt) eff_dt, Max(end_dt) end_dt
from grp
group by version_number, grp
order by eff_dt
```

Comment: Sorry but your solution only happens to work for the given data.  As soon as there are more batches that go together, your groupings fail.  For example if you add one more `INSERT VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.867' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.900' AS DateTime))` your results no longer give the desired output.  You can use lead or lag instead of a recursive cte, but you must correctly rank the inputs first.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock You were right there was a flaw. I have revisited it and taken a slightly different approach and modified my answer above, when you have a moment would you be kind enough to re-evaluate?

Comment: Yes this works.  You are now generating correct batch numbers, upon which it is easy to group.  You might want to help the OP, by explaining more clearly how you are getting the batch numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Query :

```
DROP TABLE #t1
CREATE TABLE #t1(
    [version_number] [int] NULL,
    [eff_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [end_dt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.870' AS DateTime), CAST(N'9999-12-31T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.847' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.860' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.863' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-20T17:14:55.867' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-14T15:52:50.843' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.253' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-11T15:36:25.283' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.130' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:52:45.250' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:04.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:17:23.127' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:13:03.997' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.997' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-05-06T16:00:59.990' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.370' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-19T20:45:38.993' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([version_number], [eff_dt], [end_dt]) VALUES (0, CAST(N'2021-04-13T18:03:26.483' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2021-04-16T18:35:06.367' AS DateTime))
GO


SELECT DISTINCT  t.[version_number] , eff_Table.eff_dt , end_Table.end_dt FROM #t1 t INNER JOIN
(SELECT t.version_number, t.eff_dt
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.version_number ORDER BY t.eff_dt) AS FirstID
FROM #t1 t ) AS eff_Table  ON t.version_number = eff_Table.version_number
 INNER JOIN (
SELECT t.version_number,
       t.end_dt 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.version_number ORDER BY t.end_dt desc) AS SecondID
FROM #t1 t ) AS end_Table ON end_Table.version_number = t.version_number
WHERE eff_Table.FirstID  = 1 AND end_Table.SecondID = 1
```

Comment: Your answer does not work. You don't even specify any ordering criteria for the final query, your output does not give the expected result.